# clang 8 linker error with static constexpr and arrays - what's the bug and how to work around it?

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr

When you declare a static class member that is an array constexpr, clang up to version 8 fails to link. This works in clang 9 and later, and it also works in MSVC 2019. 
https://godbolt.org/z/oQ6iEf

Can someone tell me exactly what the clang bug is and what possible workarounds I could use to express the same idea (class-static const array) with clang < 9?

Answer (score -2):

Compile with `-O1` and it will work fine ;)